# Python: Get list of all profile pictures using facebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a beginner in using facebook graph API using facebook-sdk (python package), All I want to do is get list of all my profile pictures from its album.
Here is what I am able to do:

```
photo = graph.get_objects(ids=["me"], fields="picture")
```

It gives me the current profile picture. What can I do to fetch all of them? What are all the possible values for 'fields' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the user albums first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums

Search for an album with the name "Cover Photos" and use the ID to get all photos with the `photos` edge:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/

Steps:

- `/me/albums`
- Search for the album with the name "Cover Photos"
- `/{album-id}/photos`

For example, to get the albums with the Python SDK:

```
albums = graph.get_all_connections(id='me', connection_name='albums');
```

Source: http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Yes I get that, but how to do this by using facebook-sdk (python package)?